# Undertand Node.js request object

Tags: node.js, request

I'm new to node.js so can anybody tell me the difference between http.IncomingMessage and http.ClientRequest in terms of usage ?

Answer (score 0):

`http.ClientRequest` represents an in-progress HTTP *request*. It is returned from `http.request()`. Read the documentation [here](https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_class_http_clientrequest).

`http.IncomingMessage` represents a *response* from an HTTP request. This is passed as the argument to the `'response'` event of `http.ClientRequest`. (It can also be the argument of the `'request'` event of `http.Server`.) See the documentation for this is [here](https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_class_http_incomingmessage).

Here is a basic example that shows the use of `http.ClientRequest` and `http.IncomingMessage`:

```
const http = require('http')

// We define a request to google.com
const options = {
  hostname: 'www.google.com',
  port: 80,
  path: '/',
  method: 'GET'
};

// req is a http.ClientRequest object
const req = http.request(options)

// Add a listener to req for a response. res is a http.IncomingMessage object
req.on('response', (res) => {

  // set the encoding of res
  res.setEncoding('utf8')

  // http.IncomingMessage is a readable stream, so define an event listener for data
  res.on('data', (data) => {
    console.log(data)
  })
})

// req.end() will send the request to Google
req.end()
```

The [`http.request()` documentation](https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_http_request_options_callback) shows how everything fits together.